# Can i set center child in grid? not datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, alignment

I make 5 column and 3 row grid.

ㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁ

ㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁ

ㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁ

And i add TextBlock (3 row, 1 column)

ㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁ

ㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁ

■ ㅁㅁㅁㅁ

However the TextBlock was placed in left top of (3, 1) grid.
How i can set TextBlock in center of (3, 1) by code?

Grid gd=new Grid();
gd.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
is not work.

What property i have to change?  not xaml but code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must apply the `HorizontalAlignment.Center` to the `TextBlock` not to the `Grid` :

```
TextBlock Tb=new TextBlock();
```

//...initialisation of the TextBlock

```
Tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```